# The different account types on Docker Hub registry... how it works?

Tags: docker-registry, dockerhub

I can't understand how the different "levels" or account types work in Docker Hub registry. I'll explain what I mean.

**First case**: lot of packages without a "prefix" labeled as *Official Docker Images* like `php`, `nginx`, `mariadb` etc. The URL for those repositories is prefixed with `/_/` in the path, like `hub.docker.com/_/php`.

**Second case**: lot of packages "known", with a prefix and labeled as *Sponsored OSS* like `pihole/pihole`. The URL for those repositories is prefixed with `/r/` in the path, like `hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole`.

**Regular user case**: on the contrary, when I push to Docker Hub, I'm forced to specify my username as prefix. So my images ends up to be: `<username>/foo:latest`. My page prefix is `/u/` like `hub.docker.com/u/<username>`

What this represents on Docker Hub? Will a regular user able to push images without a prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**

You have to differentiate between how data is represented on the website & URLs for humans e.g. on Docker Hub as `hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole` and the address of the images that you can pull. e.g. on the CLI with your container runtime (Docker in this case). `docker pull pihole/pihole`

The correlation you see in the URL of the UI and CLI is not chained together. For example,  `.../r/...` didn't exist a few years back.

Docker does quite a bit of magic to resolve image names. Allowing you to write something like:

`docker pull nginx` which gets resolved by the Docker runtime to `docker.io/library/nginx:latest`

Not all container runtimes behave the same, in some you have to explicitly specify a FQN like `docker.io/library/nginx:latest` in oder to fully address the image location.

If you are using a different container runtime like Podman, you could, however, customize the resolution logic to your own needs so that the runtime turns:

`podman pull my_app` to resolve into `podman pull my.container-registry.com/library/my_app:latest`